# How should I model my tables so they work well with Entify Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, database-design

So I'm trying to model the following using Entity Framework (code first).

```
public class School
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Class> Classes { get; set; }
}

public class Class
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public TypeOfClass Type { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Student> Students { get; set; } 
}

public enum TypeOfClass
{
    Kindergarten,
    HighSchool
}

public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Kid : Student
{
    public string FavouriteToy { get; set; }
}

public class Teenager : Student
{
    public int AmountOfAcne { get; set; }
}
```

I'm wondering how I should model my Entities (and tables) so that I can do something like this to select all `Student`s in the `School`:

```
var school = new School();

var kindergartenClass = new Class
{
    Name = "Kindergarten",
    Type = TypeOfClass.Kindergarten,
    Students = new List<Kid>()
};

var highschoolClass = new Class
{
    Name = "Kindergarten",
    Type = TypeOfClass.HighSchool,
    Students = new List<Teenager>()
};

school.Classes = new List<Class> {kindergartenClass, highschoolClass};

IEnumerable<Student> students = school.Classes.SelectMany(x => x.Students);
```

I wan't to have separate tables for Kids and Teenagers since they have different properties and will only share a subset och common properties.

Anyone with good advice? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, your classes should have properties that can be recognized by EF as primary keys. Normally these would be non-nullable ints with a name of Id or [ClassName]Id:

```
public class School
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // or SchoolId
}

public class Class
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // or ClassId
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // or StudentId
}
```

You have two options for mapping Kids and Teenagers to separate tables:

- Table per Type (TPT) - base class (in this case Student) gets its own table while Kids and Teenagers get one table each with foreign key associations back to the Student table.
- Table per Concrete Type (TPC) - Kid and Teenager get their own tables and all the properties from the base class (in this case the Name property from the Student class) get duplicated across all child tables.

I think what you're after is TPC. Also, I think you only want Kids and Teenagers to have tables (not Students). If so, you would need to make the Student class abstract:

```
public abstract class Student
{
    // ... 
}
```

And you would need to override the OnModelCreating method in your context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Kid>().Map(m =>
    {
        m.ToTable("Kids");
        m.MapInheritedProperties();
    });

    modelBuilder.Entity<Teenager>().Map(m =>
    {
        m.ToTable("Teenagers");
        m.MapInheritedProperties();
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, but there is/was an issue with TPC and MapInheritedProperties. I just can't remember the details right now, but in code from a few months ago I just removed that call. EF 6.1.2 .

Comment: @Henk Holterman I used EF 6.1.3 to test this code and I didn't encounter a problem. The issue you are talking about may have been fixed.

Comment: Let's hope so. I'll try to recreate my problem but that won't be today. I'll leave this note up, just in case.

Comment: I'm pulling towards using TPC due to possible performance issues with TPT. But I'm unsure how to handle [Polymormphic Associations](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt#PolymorphicAssociations) with TPC?

Answer (score 3):

You will need an Id (Key) column. And the navigation properties for collections should be `ILIst<>`.

```
public class School
{
  // Id and SchoolId are automatically recognized
  public int SchoolId { get; set; }    
  public string Name { get; set; }
  // use an IList so that you can Add()
  public IList<Class> Classes { get; set; }
}
```

for the inherited classes you will have to [pick a TPC/TPT/TPH model](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)